# Optimisation of sql query for deleting duplicate items from large table

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, amazon-rds, sql-delete

Could anyone please help me optimise one of the queries which is taking more than 20 minutes to run against 3 Million data.

Table Structure

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|id [INT Auto Inc]| name_id (uuid) | name (varchar)| city (varchar) | name_type(varchar)|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Query

The purpose of the query is to eliminate the duplicate, here duplicate means having same `name_id` and `name`.

```sql
DELETE
FROM records
WHERE id NOT IN
      (SELECT DISTINCT
          ON (name_id, name) id
       FROM records);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write your delete using exists logic:

```sql
DELETE
FROM records r1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM records r2
              WHERE r2.name_id = r1.name_id AND r2.name = r2.name AND
                    r2.id < r1.id);
```

This delete query will spare the duplicate having the smallest `id` value.  To speed this up, you may try adding the following index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON records (name_id, name, id);
```

Comment: Hi @Tim Biegeleisen, thanks for the quick answer :)  you might wanted to say `r2.name = r1.name` in answer, but apart from it, this looks good, I'll analyse the performance and comment again here.

Answer (score 1):

You probably already have a primary key on the identity column, then you can use it to exclude redundant rows by id in the following way:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT MIN(id) AS id FROM records GROUP BY name_id, name)   
DELETE FROM records
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM cte WHERE id=records.id)
```

Even without the index, this should work relatively fast, probably because of merge join strategy.